# Can't see Macbook WiFi access point on Android smartphone

Tags: wi-fi, macos, ad-hoc-networks

I'd like to connect my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Stock JellyBean) to my Macbook Pro (early-2012, running OSX Lion) via an access point created by my Macbook Pro.

Sadly I can't even see the access point on my Android phone.

Does anyone know a possible solution to this problem?

Additional information: A nearby Windows-PC and iPhone can connect to the AdHoc-network of the Macbook. The android phone can connect to all other wifi.

Comment: Can you see it from any other devices?   Can you phone see other WiFi networks?

Comment: Yes, my Windows-PC can connect to it. My phone sees all other WiFi networks.

Comment: Are you creating an Ad-hoc WiFi network? Android devices currently can't connect to ad-hoc wifi networks.

Comment: Yes I do. So that is the solution. What else could I possibly do?

Comment: The general solution would be to create a WiFi hotspot. Windows has http://www.connectify.me which can create a WiFi hotspot. You need a similar application for Mac OS. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi

Answer (score 2):

In Snow Leopard (sorry, I don't have a Lion to try this with):

In System Preferences > Sharing,

- Enable 'Internet Sharing'
- Enable 'To computers using AirPort'
- Click the 'Airport Options' button and set up hotspot's network name and encryption. The AirPort will have to be off for this button to be active.
- 'Ok' to back out to the Sharing pref pane.

On the Network Preference Pane, or on the menu bar,

- Turn on the AirPort.

Your device should see your Mac as a WiFi access point.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to expand on the [previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33194):

The stock Android OS doesn't see Ad-Hoc wifi points - this has been programmed in. Why Google decided this, I have no idea.

The wifi access point, as you said, is an Ad-Hoc network, as such Android doesn't see it.

The previous answer tells you how to turn the Ad-Hoc network into a wifi access point - like the ones routers use.

Most custom ROMs allow you to connect to Ad-Hoc networks as if they were normal wifi hotspots.

Comment: I assume the logic is to (slightly) raise the barrier necessary to mess with people at starbucks or something and sniff everyone's phone traffic by making an ad-hoc mimicking a commonly trusted network.